# Sharing Ubuntu Desktop on the Internet

Tags: 10.04, port-forwarding, dyndns

At home, I have Ubuntu Linux 10.04 on a spare laptop and a DSL connection that's always on. What are the steps to **securely** (very important) share this on the web with like DynDNS or something and port forwarding so that I can access it over port 443 (HTTPS port) over the web and access the GUI of the desktop? My DSL router supports port forwarding.

See, sometimes I'm in a hotel with bad Internet (only ports 80 and 443 available) and need a way to connect to a power user workstation so that I can do emergency systems operations tasks for my employer.

Comment: Any reason you need a full desktop, or would command-line ssh work?

Comment: Just easier to multitask -- it's what I'm used to, moving windows around with multiple terminal sessions, minimizing stuff out of my way, browsing a site, doing cut/paste between windows, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have many tools to do this.
you can use Teamviewer , FreeNX,VNC.

**Installation of FreeNX:**

Open your terminal and paste these lines one by one.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:freenx-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freenx
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenx-server/+bug/576359/+attachment/1378450/+files/nxsetup.tar.gz
tar -xvf nxsetup.tar.gz
sudo cp nxsetup /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup
sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
```

**To Install TeamViewer**
open your terminal and type this

```
wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

For More Information:
 [FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) , [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)